# Doubt about a simple equation in Srednicki's QFT textbook

Tags: quantum-field-theory, spacetime, causality

On page 30, he writes ($ Px = P^\mu x_\mu = \textbf{P} \cdot \textbf{x} - H t $)

$$ e^{-i P x /\hbar } \varphi(0) e^{i P x /\hbar } = \varphi(x) ,\tag{2.21}$$

which he states is a  relativistic generalization of the Heisenberg equation

$$ e^{iH t /\hbar } \varphi(\textbf{x}, 0) e^{-i Ht/ \hbar} = \varphi(\textbf{x}, t )\tag{2.20}$$

in quantum mechanics.

I am confused here. By this equation, the whole field $\varphi(x)$ is determined by its value at $0 = (\textbf{0},  t =0)$. How could this be true? At  $t =0 $, the field should can take independent values at different positions. **There should be no relation between $\varphi(0, 0 )$ and $\varphi(\textbf{x}, 0)$ actually.**

Comment: Are you comfortable with Taylor series and its codification in the [Lagrange shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator)?

Comment: @CosmasZachos   I am confident with my quantum mechanics background, but when it comes to QFT, I am often baffled. I know in QM, $ [e^{i p a } f] (x) = f(x + a )$, i.e., $e^{i p a }$ is a shift operator. But the function $f$ take independent values at different positions!

Comment: Nothing to do with QM or QFT…. Don’t overthink it…It’s plain analysis… you are looking at a Taylor series!

Comment: Taylor expand $f(x)$ around $x=0$. Assume convergent. Use that to compute $f(x)$ at arbitrary $x$. How can $f(0)$ tell us about $f(x)$ at arbitrary $x$ values? This simple case may shed light on the apparent paradox

Answer (score 2):

Recall that the total 4-momentum operator $P^{\mu}$ is an integral over a whole [Cauchy surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_surface) $$\Sigma~=~\{t\!=\!0\},$$ and hence contains all initial data needed to determine the system in an arbitrary future and past spacetime point.

Comment: The explicit expression of $P^\mu$? Does it depend on the theory?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.